# Fixed search bar inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of 50 players which are called player{1..50} and created a search input where I can filter them by name.

I am having issues keeping the search input in place while scrolling.

If I set it to `fixed` or `absolute`, it ignores the parent div limits, as it should, which is an issue as I want it to stay inside the parent div, as it is now.

How can I achieve this so the search bar stays in the same place while you scroll through the Players?

I have read through several questions already to find a solution but haven't had any luck for my specific case.

Full code can be seen here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nullpointer9/f748qnks/

(Make sure to extend the window for easier use)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a simple way to do this is by using the new [`position: sticky;`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)).

```
.job-search {
    position: sticky;   /* The magic */
    z-index: 1;         /* Ensure it stays on top of other player divs */
    top: 0px;           /* Where it should stick to */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to tell it where to point to if it is inside a div

```
 .row-main .main-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #131313;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: this just adds position: fixed to my existing css styling. I don't have an issue selecting the element via css, but avoiding the effect that position: fixed does. Is it working for you?